# What does the abreviation INFLNFL stand for and what is the difference between INFLNFL and INFL?

Tags: linguistic-typology

What does the abreviation INFLNFL stand for? What is the meaning of INFLNFL and where does it appear in the syntactic tree-construction?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE, Bettina! For the sake of completeness, could you provide a bit more of context? Where did you see/hear these acronyms? What triggered your curiosity about this?

Comment: Assuming you're interested in linguistics proper, INFL was proposed in Chomsky 1981, from INFL(ection); now it is usually known as T. As for INFLNFL, it looks like some notation no longer used, either - Chomsky 1993?

Comment: I concur with @AlexB. that INFL just looks like Chomsky's T, but I haven't seen INFLNFL anywhere except (by Google search) a single article on Spanish grammar where it could possibly be a typo. Do you have more context? where did you see this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's the same, but I've seen this sort of annotation used quite a bit in Spanish. It's also a characteristic of the language though, even outside the world of linguistics. 'Los Estados Unidos' is often shortened to 'los EEUU'.
Here is an excerpt from a website on Spanish syntax, in which the author refers to SN (sintagma nominal) in its singular & plural form as such: 'los SSNN' (los = plural, definite article) /'un SN' (un = singular, indefinite article).
SN (sintagma nominal) is just the Spanish equivalent of the English NP (noun phrase).

[image: http://www.ugr.es/~jsantana/publicaciones/degenerativa.htm]

Comment: Acronyms are always doubled in Spanish when pluralised, but as you also write them, the doubling happens to each _individual_ letter that represents a pluralised word. INFLNFL doesn’t match that; if it had been the plural of an acronym INFL, it would be INNFFLL (assuming that the single I represents a word that’s not pluralised).